# How to automate upload multiple files (Katalon Studio) when there is no attribute "multiple" in tag input?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, katalon-studio

i want to automate upload multiple files (Katalon Studio), but there is no attribute "multiple" like this

```
<input type="file" multiple>
```

but instead like the img1 below.
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqyle.png)

what i want to achieve is like
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGXZP.png)

I've tried to make it like this, the steps produce passed but no files are uploaded

```
def documentsPath = ['E:\\\\FfzsHZJUcAEvXrs.jpeg', 'E:\\\\FeNebInVIAApKzh.jpg', 'E:\\\\FeNebZTVIAADXR5.jpg', 'E:\\\\FfzsWUPVQAAO-SL.jpeg']

for (path in documentsPath) {
    WebUI.uploadFile(findTestObject('homepage/pemasaranku/register supplier/ipt_dokumen_supplier'), path, FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)
}
```

Comment: Use WebUI.Sendkeys() to send the files.